# KNockout JS - Loading external templates

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

Hi folks I am building a CRUD system very similar to this example http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/WpnTU/.

**Context:**

I have several HTML pages that each contain the same table of data but showing different information (each page have their diffirent use).

On each row theres an edit button like yuo see in the example. Since the modal form is the same accross all the HTML pages I decided to create one HTML page containing the modal form. I then use jquerys load function like so `$("#load_modal").load("pages/modal_form.html");`  on each of the HTML pages.

**Problem:**

On a basic HTML page this is working out great. I tought this was a brilliant approach and gave myself a pat on the back. But now the problem I have is that when started implementing knockout it dosent seems to be working together very well. Modal dosent always pop up correctly and such.

**My question:**

At this point im not looking to figure out my code issue. I spent days and weeks staring at it and I came to the conclusion that I need to rethink my approach altogether. Im curios to hear some of your opnions on what would be the best aproach to tackle something like this.

**Ideas so far:**

- I found this https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-amd-helpers/tree/master/examples But dosent use the latest knockout version and seems more complicated for something simple I need.
- I also saw that using requireJS would be another idea but honestly these seem to complicate things for me.

Would anyone know of a simpler template solution or even have a whole different approach to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery to modify your DOM is not going to work well in Knockout. You can use [components](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-overview.html) to define the form HTML. Use an observable to switch which component is displayed.